# How do I checkin only the relevant parts of bower components?

Tags: bower

I am using bower in a client-side project.  Not all devs will have bower on their machine, so we need to include all bower dependencies in our source repo. But we are only allowed to check in the parts of the bower_components directory that are directly being used by the project (ie- only check in css/js/html files, and avoid checking in test, docs, etc).

Is there an existing script that can help with this, or do I need to manually go through and delete all unwanted pieces of bower components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately that's the only safe way you can do it, for now. The real solution is to encourage package authors to add unneeded files to the `ignore` property in their bower.json.

Comment: Thanks. Any plans for improving this by for example (optionally) heuristically ignoring certain files or folders?

Comment: Any heuristic will be fragile and will never be included in core. Though you're free to create your own tool and there might already be some.